# JWT OAuth token in WebSphere 9.0 TAI

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, oauth, websphere, websphere-9

I have configured the WebSphere with TAI and able to get it authenticated using Bearer token(Postman). Is there any way to get JWT based Bearer token.

Comment: @Chunlong if you could help me on this.

Comment: If this is Liberty profile, you can follow this link, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.oidc_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/security/openidconnect/PropagationHelper.html.

Comment: For traditional WebSphere, follow this link, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/security/oidc/util/package-summary.html